# Здравствуйте! Пожалуйста подскажите как сделать ввод массива и кол-во элементов массива в данном примере?

Tags: c, массивы, for

```
const int Max = 100;
float A[Max];
float avg = 0;
int i, n;

for(i = 0; i < n; i++)
  {
    avg += A[i];
  }
 
   printf("Array average is %f",   avg /= n);
```

для высчета среднего арифметического элементов массива вещественных чисел - цикл for. Ввод массива и элементов с консоли при помощи scanf

Answer (score 0):

И зачем вам для этого массив?...

```
int n;
scanf("%d",&n);
for(int i = 0; i < n; i++)
{
    float x;
    scanf("%f",&x);
    avg += x;
}
```

Ну, проверки, что все введено верно, расставьте сами...